# Can't start mac because startup disk is missing

Tags: macos, disk-utility, recovery, startup

First off, I apologize if this is kind of jumbled. I am just extremely stressed because of this.

Long story short, i fell asleep with my mac playing Netflix. When I wake up i have to plug it in because it died and when i plugged it in, it would only load bootcamp. I go to select the startup disk and Macintosh HD is gone. Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

It is important that I recover my data. I have an old time machine backup if that would help in any way. Is there a way to use it or an external drive to somehow get the files if they still exist?

Comment: If you don’t have a backup and want to recover data, best to add that to the question, clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer: boot into [recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) and open disk utility.  If the SSD is visible, do “first aid.”

What to do next depends on what you see in Disk Utility.

Comment: They are already booted to recovery, but proper next steps. Run first aid, erase and then reinstall are all up next...

Comment: @bmike i cant. i need to save my data if possible and the "disk1s2" is where Macintosh hd should be and i cant interact with it.

Comment: So, if you can’t risk losing the data, shut down and contact Drive Savers for a quote. Repair may erase the content or do damage. It also could be fixable if only the partition table failed. What are the odds just that one small sector broke?netflix doesn’t alter boot records, so this might be bad news...